# Actions class sendkeys down-arrow does not work in any browser

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE03j.png)Hi,Iam new to selenium and java testing. Iam trying to right click on google.com about link and open the link in new window.  Up to right click my code works fine. When I send down-arrow nothing happens in the browser. Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code. I have tried it in all different browsers.

Comment: Why is element inside the send keys?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].